# What is the procedure in case the ISS loses one of the evacuation crafts?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft, safety

Suppose that a micrometeorite or a sudden failure renders one of the Soyuz inoperable, or that a routine inspection discovers a defect in one of them that makes it unsafe.

What is the protocol to follow in this case? I assume that the ISS is not under any threat and does not need immediate evacuation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The crew of the nonfunctional spacecraft would have to wait

> without an
> escape capability until a Soyuz replacement or a Shuttle arrives (either of which could
> take days to months depending on timing).

(Nowadays read Crew Dragon for Shuttle)

[Final Report of the ISS Independent Safety Task Force](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/170368main_IIST_%20Final%20Report.pdf) p.52

Comment: This would be a huge advertisement for SpaceX, if the crew had a week to evacuate from a problem during this time, and SpaceX was able to send a craft up there much faster than government agencies.

Comment: @Panzercrisis it would be interesting to know how fast they could turn one around.

Comment: Decision might also hinge on how much supplies the crew has in storage.  Assuming they have enough food and water to last a few months (mostly food since water can be recycled), they might be okay.  If they're running low, it might be expedited...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman they plan the supplies so that any one supply ship can be missed without causing a huge problem.

Comment: @Panzercrisis don't put bad ideas in Elon's head, he has an abundance of those already

Comment: @llama So it's Elon drilling holes in Soyuz after all